# How to find definitions in standard librarys using the gcc preprocessor?

Tags: grep, gcc, c

I have found in my project a type definition, which is definitely from a standard library. Lets say the definition is called

```
uint64_t
```

. I would like to know, what definition is exactly behind that uint64_t? Further stdint.h is included. How to use gcc preprocessor in order to know exactly what the `uint64_t` is in my system?

Comment: yes it goes in that direction, gcc -E is the actual flag I'm searching (mentioned in your link).
It stops the compiler after preprocessor stage and outputs the actual includes and type definitions without all the #ifdef's to stdout.

Comment: You may also want to look at things like `cscope` or `ctags` that integrate nicely in some text editors or IDEs like `vim`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we were looking for the definition of an uint64 in my 64bit Debian system this is the command I was looking for:

```
echo | gcc -E -xc -include stdint.h -include stddef.h - | grep uint64_t
```

outputs

```
typedef unsigned long int uint64_t;
```

Probably this command is lurking around here and there, but I couldn't find it implicitly.

Comment: Note that this finds the standard `uint64_t` type, not some unknown `uint64` type.

Comment: Oh yes, I meant uint64_t

Comment: That type is, per the C standard, defined in `stdint.h`.  Why do you need to search for it?

Comment: @Kusalananda It's just an example, because that struct I was searching for wasn't within any library at all. I edited the struct from __IO to uint64_t so the question makes somehow sense.